# How do I escape an apostrophe in my XPath text query with Perl and Selenium?

Tags: regex, perl, xpath, selenium, apostrophe

I have an XPath query which needs to match some text in a span attribute, as follows:

```
my $perl_query = qq(span[text\(\)='It's a problem']);

$sel->click_ok($perl_query);
```

Where the text has no apostrophe there is no problem.

I've tried the following instead of 'It's a problem':

```
'It\'s a problem'
'It&apos\;s a problem'
'It\${apos}s a problem'  #some thread on Stackoverflow suggested that this was a solution implemented by Selenium, but it doesn't work.
```

Any ideas?

On a different note, if I can't solve this, I'd be happy enough matching 'a problem' but not sure how to do regex matching in XPath with Selenium.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 4):

It's an XPath problem rather than the Perl problem.

The problem was discussed and answered here in great detail:
http://kushalm.com/the-perils-of-xpath-expressions-specifically-escaping-quotes (broken link; check the [WayBack
Machine archive here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180917002022/http://kushalm.com/the-perils-of-xpath-expressions-specifically-escaping-quotes))

In a nutshell, modify your xquery to assemble the quote-containing string using `concat()`

```
my $perl_query = qq(span[text\(\)=concat("It","'","s a problem"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions; hopefully at least one of them will work:

```
my $perl_query = qq!span[text()='It\\'s a problem']!;
my $perl_query = qq!span[text()="It's a problem"]!;
```

Comment: Thanks - but none of these worked... (and it isn't a curly quote either).

So in the end I captured and looped through all span values, then used normal perl regex to match that to my string, as in:
my $text = $sel->get_text()  #insert XPath to span element in parantheses
#use everyday perl to see if $text contains "It's a problem"

Comment: This worked great, since in chrome I needed to have quotes already around the entire xpath:
$x("//div[.=\"My friend's value is here?\"]/../ul/li")

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and google didn't give me a satisfied solution.

I tried to substring this: **value='** - ending with an Apostrophe.

My XPath that works look like:

`"substring-after(., concat('value=', ''''))"`

So four Apostrophes in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Well the post is quite old. But here goes my working answer for those who still come wandering around looking for escaping single apostrophe and unable to find proper answer.

```
Text = It's a problem

Solution xpath = //div[text()=\"It's a problem\"]

or

Solution xpath = //div[contains(text(),\"It's a\")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the actual text on the web page is a curly quote and not a straight apostrophe?  Also, you may have extra space at the beginning and end of the span, so that the strict equality against your string won't match.

Answer (score 0):

Consider breaking up your string if possible:

```
my $spanValue = q/text()='It's a problem'/;
my $perlQuery = qq/span[$spanValue]/;

# $perlQuery = span[text()='It's a problem']
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to escaping apostrophes in xpath string literals is to double the apostrophe, e.g.
qq(span[text()='It''s a problem'])